# AMP: Select option and change option in another element

Tags: html-select, amp-html

This is written with AMP HTML.

There are two  lists with all states and then some extras. These lists are over 50 selections.

There is one  list for billing info and one list for destination state.

When a person selects a state on the billing  list, I'd like the destination  list to change to that state.
The shipping state list should be able to be changed by the user.

Here is sample code with a few options, not all of them. I think I captured the selected "Billing State" as "billstate" but don't know how to make it selected in the "Destination State".

In the AMP documentation, I don't see anything I can bind like [selected]="selectedbillstate".
And, then how would the code find the right state to change to "selected"?
And, how would I designate the  to indicate which destination state to select.

```
<label for "state">Billing State</label>
<select name="state" id="state" required on="input-debounced:AMP.setState({billstate: event.value })">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select the State</option>
    <option value="APO-AP">APO</option>
    <option value="FPO">FPO</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
</select>

<label for "sstate">Destination State</label>
<select name="sstate" id="sstate" required >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select the State</option>
    <option value="APO-AP" >APO</option>
    <option value="FPO">FPO</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="APO-AP" on="tab:AMP.setState({sstatelist: true })"> APO</option>
...
<select name="sstate" id="sstate" required [disabled]="sstatelist ? true : false">
```

Basically you're creating a variable "sstatelist" which is set to false by default. When the <option> is chosen, the disabled state is set to false, hence the <select> element gets enabled.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22738035)

Comment: Your answer came in lower quality posts. Please provide some explanation even though your code is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I found another way. AMP folks said there IS a [selected] var.
This is the billing select:

```
<select name="state" id="state" required="" on="input-debounced:AMP.setState({billstate: event.value })">
```

This is the shipping option. The sstate==null is to prevent the shipping option from changing if a customer *changes* the billing state.

```
<select name="country" id="country" required="" on="input-debounced:AMP.setState({billcountry: event.value })">
<option value="APO-AP" [selected]="billstate==\'APO-AP\' && sstate==null" >APO</option>
```